# Interface API calls with generic type

Tags: c#, .net, interface, json.net, implementation

I want to be able to switch between API providers and achieve the same result.

I have an interface called IApi that I am using for both APIs.

```
public interface IApi
{
    T GetData<T>();
}
```

I then have my two API classes implementing this interface

```
public class ApiOne: IApi
{
    private IWebClient _client;
    public ApiOne(IWebClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    public T GetData<T>()
    {
        return _client.Get<T>($"{some specific url for this api");
    }
}

public class ApiTwo: IApi
{
    private IWebClient _client;
    public ApiTwo(IWebClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    public T GetData<T>()
    {
        return _client.Get<T>($"{some specific url for this api");
    }
}
```

Both of these calls obviously return different JSON responses depending on the API. I am using Newtonsoft to deserialze the responses into strong typed classes.
Which means I have 3 data models. 1 for each API response and a 3rd which is what I would like to transform the API responses into so that I can use only one data model as the Generic type.

```
public class ApiOneResponse
{
    public string FieldOne { get; set; }
    public string FieldTwo { get; set; }
}
public class ApiTwoResponse
{
    public string SomeOtherFieldOne { get; set; }
    public string SomeOtherFieldTwo { get; set; }
}
```

How can I achieve this so that both my API calls can be deserialized down to the same class and I can call it with a simple one liner?

```
public class CommonResponse
{
    public string CommonFieldOne { get; set; }
    public string CommonFieldTwo { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to simply call it like the below

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
    //some additional logic

    //call the API
    var response = _api.GetData<CommonResponse>();
 }
```

**EDIT**
The issue is that _webClient.Get will try and deserialise the JSON properties into CommonResonse and each JSON reponse cannot be directly mapped into CommonResponse as the JSON keys would be different on each response.

Below is the WebClient code

```
public class WebClient : IWebClient
{
    public T Get<T>(string endpoint)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(endpoint).Result;
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what does the call to `_client.Get<T>()` exactly do? The `var response = _api.GetData<CommonResponse>();` is allowed by your current design, so what's the actual problem?

Comment: @SashaStojanovic you can your interface `IApi` generic itself

Comment: @OndrejTucny I have edited the original question with a better explanation of the final issue.

Comment: `WebClient` is the name of an obsolete class still available in .NET Framework. It's a *really* bad idea to use that name. It's also a *bad* idea to use `.Result` and block on asynchronous methods. Network operations are asynchronous, HttpClient is asynchronous so *your* code has to be asynchronous as well

Comment: PS: you're misusing HttpClient too. It's a thread-safe class that's meant to be reused. Check [You're using HttpClient wrong and it is destabilizing your software](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) and [Use HttpClientFactory to implement resilient HTTP requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that's fine. I can easily refactor and fix that. That's not my current issue but thanks.

Comment: What you try to do, in its correct form, would be a [typed client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests#how-to-use-typed-clients-with-httpclientfactory)

Comment: @SashaStojanovic JSON has no types or inheritance and JSON.NET can't guess what type to use by itself. If both client and server used JSON.NET, you could have the server [emit type information](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm). That's a JSON.NET extension though, not supported by anyone else or even System.Text.Json in .NET Core

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetData` doesn't need to be generic if you're always returning a `CommonResponse`:

```
public interface IApi
{
    CommonResponse GetData();
}
```

Then in each implementation, project the response to your `CommonResponse`:

```
public class ApiOne: IApi
{
    private IWebClient _client;
    public ApiOne(IWebClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    public CommonResponse GetData()
    {
        var response = _client.Get<ApiOneResponse>($"{some specific url for this api");
        return new CommonResponse
        {
            CommonFieldOne = response.FieldOne,
            CommonFieldTwo = response.FieldTwo
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How very true!!! (face palm). Shows what another set of eyes can do :D. Thanks man!